# Freehand draw on Leaflet (Mobile)

Tags: leaflet, drawing

I wrote a very simple method that works on Desktop with a mouse. But on touchscreen devices, as expected, the map is dragged and not drawn on.

```
var drawMode = false;
var myDrawing;

//some button that toggles on drawing, for now just manually doing it in console for testing.

map.on('click', function() 
{
  if (drawMode) 
  {
    myDrawing = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);
  }
})

map.on('mousemove', function(e) 
{
  if (drawMode) 
  {
    myDrawing.addLatLng(e.latlng);
  }
})
```

Is there anyway to disable dragging the map while in drawing mode? My end goal is just to toggle draw mode on and off with a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable map drag with `map.dragging.disable()` and enable it with `map.dragging.enable()`